# gradle AbortException: FileNotFoundException when minifyEnable=true

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project where we just upgraded to gradle wrapper 4.9-all and using gradle tools plugin com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha04. I have different build variants. The build types using proguard and minifyEnabled=true are failing because they can't find the /libs folder:

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: /Users/username/projects/projectA/path-to-project/libs, java.io.FileNotFoundException:/Users/username/projects/projectA/path-to-project/libs (Is a directory)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:119)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:251)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:229)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.R8.lambda$run$0(R8.java:134)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:55)

If i set minifyEnabled=false, then the build completes successfully. 
I have googled and haven't found anything specific to this issue. Is anyone else running into this?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] It was a proguard issue. In my proguard-rules.pro file, there was a setting of

> -injars  libs

The intent was to apply to all jars in the libs folder.
Well...somewhere between upgrading to gradle-wrapper 4.9
the behavior with proguard changed. Now I have to explicitly specify the
jar files.

```
-injars libs/a.jar
-injars libs/b.jar
-injars libs/c.jar
etc...
```